# Eclipse Plugin Singleton setting

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin that houses Custom Xpath functions that can be accessed by all projects in the workspace. While creating the plugin, it created it as a singleton because it required extensions and extension points. Is this done so that the Custom functions are registered only once?

[ ] This plug-in is a singleton

Also at runtime, does this mean that all application that leverage the custom functions need to wait for another application before they can call the custom functions? If so, wont this slow everything down? Or can they concurrently call the functions and do not have a wait dependency among each other to the plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All this flag does is ensure that only a single **version** of the plug-in is loaded. So if both version 1.0.0 and version 2.0.0 of the plug-in were present in the RCP only one of them would be used (normally the highest version).

It does not affect the way the plug-in executes in any way.

From the OSGi specification for 'Bundle-SymbolicName':

> singleton - Indicates that the bundle can only have a single version
>   resolved in an environment. A value of true indicates that the bundle
>   is a singleton bundle. The default value is false. The Framework must
>   resolve at most one bundle when multiple versions of a singleton
>   bundle with the same symbolic name are installed.